# Access violation with Ctypes Python <> Fortran DLL

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes

I'm trying to make Python use a Fortran DLL (call by referance). When running Fortran 90 code, it works fine, but will not work in Python; it only gives "access violation" errors or "called with not enough arguments".

The python code:

```
from ctypes import *
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("test.dll")

# This function works.
print mydll.XIT() # prints 0

mydll.GetInfo.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_char_p)]

rm = c_int()
rf = c_int()
vm = (c_int * 5)()
vf = (c_int * 5)()
np = c_int(14)
p = (c_int * 14)()
filename = "test"
fn = c_char_p(filename)
nc = c_int(len(filename)) # length of string. (Hidden argument in Fortran)

# throws insufucient arguments
print mydll.GetInfo(rm,rf,vm,vf,np,p,fn,nc)

# throws access violation
print mydll.GetInfo(byref(rm),byref(rf),byref(vm),byref(vf),byref(np),byref(p),byref(fn),byref(nc))
```

The fortran90 code:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: np = 14 
  integer :: rm, rf
  integer, dimension(5) :: vm, vf
  integer, dimension(np) :: p
  character(len=80) :: fn
  interface
    integer function GetInfo(rm, rf, vm, vf, np, p, fn)
    !dec$ attributes dllimport, stdcall, reference, decorate, alias:'GetInfo' :: GetInfo
      implicit none
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: fn
      integer, intent(in) :: np
      integer, intent(out) :: rm,rf
      integer, intent(out), dimension(5) :: vm,vf
      integer, intent(out), dimension(np) :: p
    end function GetInfo
  end interface
  fn = "test"
  print *, GetInfo(rm, rf, vm, vf, np, p, fn)
end program test
```

Edit:
I've modified my code to now not pass the string length as reference. I've switched the cdll to windll, and removed the double POINTER and byref() usage. Also, c_char_p is already a pointer, so it doesn't need a POINTER.

Comment: You know, it's not like your compiler charges you more to compile longer variable names. Just saying...

Comment: @Stefano The Fortran is someone else's code and written the long tradition of very short names. Makes sense to use the same names on the other side of the boundary.

Comment: @David Heffernan: The original names are so short you could just use them as prefixes.

Comment: You indicate in an edit to the question that the problem was the string length passing. Was that really the only thing wrong? Also, you should not update your question to say "SOLVED". You should either accept an answer an acceptable one exists, or add one of your own and accept that. This site is meant to be in the Q&A format.

Comment: Sorry, I found no way to mark comments to answers, so I made an edit isntead..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure on what the conventions of your Fortran compiler are so I'll answer with some general points rather than specifics:

1. Your calling conventions don't match. The Fortran code specifies stdcall and the ctypes code specifies cdecl. You need to make them match up. For example, change the ctypes to use `windll` rather than `cdll`.
2. Are you sure that `POINTER(c_char_p)` is right? That is a pointer to a pointer to null-terminated string. I think you probably have an extra layer of indirection at the Python end, but I'm not 100% sure of that.
3. @eryksun states in a comment that the implicit string length parameter is passed by value rather than by reference.

Otherwise I can't see anything wrong, although I know nothing whatsoever about Fortran so I can't vouch for that.

If I were you I would cut this right back to a trivial function that passes a single int parameter. Then I would add an int array and check that you can transfer data both ways for such a parameter. Then move up to a string. Don't attempt such a complicated parameter list from scratch because you just give yourself too many potential pitfalls and it's hard to know where to look first.

Comment: It's not my DLL, so unfortunately, there are no easier functions to use :\ I will try with  windll! The POINTER(), was just one of the ways I tried to make it work, as I saw some forum posts where it was successful.

Comment: No probs. Write your own fortran DLL with suitably simple functions. In the meantime fix the calling convention and see if that helps.

Comment: @user1064136: The length of the string is passed by value, not by reference.